# CSS not working when deploying a Jekyll site

Tags: css, docker, deployment, gitlab, jekyll

I just installed Jekyll and generated a new site and modified almost nothing of the default configuration.
I can serve it well locally.
But when I push the source code to Github Pages or deploy it on Gitlab with a build script, I have the same result: the CSS doesn't load.
I haven't changed anything in the layout. I thought this would be the kind of feature that should work by default.

The repo:
https://github.com/bmrejen/jekyll_blog

The Github Pages: 
https://bmrejen.github.io/jekyll_blog/

Answer (score 0):

It says

> "Could not find the original style sheet."

Try to add this in `jekyll_blog/_config.yml`

```
baseurl: /PROJECT
url: http://USERNAME.github.io
```

I saw in your history you deleted the URL & baseurl and insert it wrong.
If you still can't understand how to insert, you can watch this tutorial, it's cover it:
[Hosting on Github Pages](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fqFjuX4VZmU)